# Condition for the convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} t^\gamma e^{i v t^p} dt$.

Tags: complex-analysis

This integral is Example 6.3.3 of "Complex variables" by Ablowitz and Fokas.

$$\int_0^{\infty} t^\gamma e^{i v t^p} dt = \left(\frac{1}{v}\right)^{\frac{\gamma+1}{p}}\frac{\Gamma\left({\frac{\gamma+1}{p}}\right)}{p} e^{\frac{i \pi}{2p}(\gamma+1)}$$

The book says that the integral converges for $p > 0$ and $\gamma > -1$.
It changes the contour to the line of the direction $e^{i \pi/2p}$ and introduce the variable $u = v t^p$ to express the integral in the form of the gamma function.
[Here](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=HoMhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA442&lpg=PA442&dq=Example%206.3.3%20%22Complex%20variables%22%20Ablowitz%20Fokas&source=bl&ots=VWavo0IDzC&sig=q1BiEWhNjNFt93ji9xw_Cy0JslE&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAGoVChMIjMrtzIqcxwIVwRumCh1crg7y#v=onepage&q=Example%206.3.3%20%22Complex%20variables%22%20Ablowitz%20Fokas&f=false) is the page of the book from google books

However, I guess $\gamma$ and $p$ should satisfy  $-1 < \gamma < p - 1$.
If $\gamma > 0$ then $t^\gamma \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$. To cancel out the divergence, the oscillation of the exponential factor should be fast enough as $t \to \infty$. Thus $p$ should be large enough. But I cannot make a rigorous proof for my guess.

Comment: Are $\gamma, p, v$ supposed to be complex or real?

Comment: They are assumed to be reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing variables $x=vt^p$ makes the integral simpler to work with

$$\int_0^{\infty} t^\gamma e^{i v t^p}\,{\rm d}t = \frac{1}{p}\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)^{\frac{\gamma+1}{p}}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{\gamma+1}{p}-1} e^{ix}\,{\rm d}x$$

Let $q = \frac{\gamma+1}{p}-1$ and consider the imaginary part of the integral above split into sums over intervals on the form $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$ using $\sin(k\pi + x) = (-1)^k\sin(x)$:
$$\int_0^\infty x^q \sin(x)\,{\rm d}x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}\int_0^{\pi}(\pi k + x)^q\sin(x)\,{\rm d}x \equiv \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(-1)^{k}$$ 
where a simple estimate gives $a_k > 2(\pi k)^q$. Thus if $q\geq 0\implies \gamma\geq p-1$ we have $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k \not = 0$ and the sum and therefore the integral does not exist.